# Single-word and non-gender specific term for "every man jack"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I'm working on a book or blog series concept typifying a role (a software product manager) in a very down-to-earth way, and not in the glorified manner it is often described. I am trying to find a word (adjective) that describes the "every day hero" version of product managers (which are very common) and not the "superhero" versions.

Here's more background on the concept: Most of the time, product managers are described in a very idealistic sense, working at a Silicon Valley elite company, with a lot of support from the executives of the company that doesn't exist in most small- or medium-sized "normal" technology companies. Thus, the majority of "everyday" product managers can't relate to these role descriptions and become frustrated by the literature.

I have found that there are important principles that need to be implemented for the "everyday" product manager.

I'm looking for something along the lines of "every day hero" (think nurse or healthcare worker)  in contrast to "superhero" (Superman, etc.). Something that exemplifies grit, down-to-earthiness, hard work, generally non-unique and inconspicuous, but extremely valuable under the surface.

I've done some research, and found that "every man jack" may possibly describe these people, but it is out-of-date and Jack is still generally considered to be a man's name. The definition of "every man jack" is: `everyone without exception`, which doesn't quite harp on the idea. Source: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/every-man-jack

I'm looking for a word in the English language that conveys these principles in a concise way that is not gender specific.

Example: *A Guide for the `Everyday` Product Manager*

^ I am trying to replace the term `Everyday` with a better adjective

Comment: How about "every man Pat"?

Comment: It doesn't really fit, but I was reminded of _The **Accidental** DBA_. Another thought was simply _fallible_, and still another _"Common or Garden"_ as a phrase similar to "every man Jack".